# jQuery .each and setTimeout not working well together

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

why is this returning undefined for all ID's?

```
var time = 200;

$('.block').each(function () { 
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        }, time);

    time += 200;
});
```

but this returns the ID's just fine?

```
var time = 200;

$('.block').each(function () { 
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));

    setTimeout(function () {
        }, time);

    time += 200;
});
```

I'm trying to create a sort of bubbling in one at a time effect and this is driving me crazy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `this` inside the callback (the global object) is not the same as in the outer scope (where it's the current element). Use the following to close over a reference to the correct value:

```
$('.block').each(function () { 
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(that.attr('id'));
    }, time);
    time += 200;
});
```

This works because the function passed to `setTimeout` is a closure that retains access to the variables declared in its lexical scope (which includes `that`).

The *general* lesson here is that the value of `this` inside a function is determined dynamically and depends entirely on *how* the function was executed:

- jQuery executes the outer function and explicitly sets `this` to the current element (using `call`/`apply`).
- The browser executes the inner function in a global context, which is why the value of `this` is `window` there. This simple test demonstrates that last point:

  ```
  setTimeout(function() {
      alert(this === window); // true
  }, 1000)
  ```

In modern browsers, an alternative to the solution above is to use `bind`:

```
$('.block').each(function () { 
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    }.bind(this), time);
    time += 200;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When the `setTimeout` runs the value of `this` has changed. To fix this you can cache the `this` value in your `.each()` loop so it will be available to the anonymous function in your `setTimeout`:

```
var time = 200;
$('.block').each(function () { 
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log($this.attr('id'));
        }, time);

    time += 200;
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FRzWc/

Also if you want to improve the performance of your loop quite a bit then use `$.each()` instead of `.each()`:

```
var time = 200;
$.each($('.block'), function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.text($this.attr('id'));
        console.log($this.attr('id'));
        }, time);

    time += 200;
});
```